# pytest monkepatch, decorate stub instead of replace

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

So I have the following example code:

```
import pytest

class Helper:
    def function1(self):
        print("helper function called")

class SUT:
    def real_function(self):
        helper = Helper()
        helper.function1()
        print("real function called")

def test_Test(monkeypatch):
    test = SUT()
    def stub_function1(self):
        print("helper is stubbed")

    monkeypatch.setattr(Helper, "function1", stub_function1)
    test.real_function()
```

and running `pytest .\test_scratch_1.py --capture=tee-sys` prints out `helper is stubbed` and `real function called`, as expected.

However, I would actually like to be able print out `helper function called` before `helper is stubbed`, thus not fully stubbing the function but rather sort of decorate the function with things to do after it runs. I tried the following:

```
import pytest

class Helper:
    def function1(self):
        print("helper function called")

class SUT:
    def real_function(self):
        print("real function called")

def test_Test(monkeypatch):
    test = SUT()
    helper_original = Helper()
    def stub_function1(helper_original_not_stubbed):
        helper_original_not_stubbed.function1()
        print("helper is stubbed")

    monkeypatch.setattr(Helper, "function1", stub_function1(helper_original))
    test.real_function()
```

But this produces the same result. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: `test` is a nonlocal name in the definition of `stub_function`. When you *call* `stub_function1`, `test.function1` has to be evaluated to see what to call, that that expression evaluates to `stub_function1` when the patch is in place.

Comment: `stub_function1` does *not* wrap a call to the original method, because nothing in the body of the function is evaluated *before* the function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a decorator around your method prior to calling it.

```py
def my_decorator(function):
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print("before")
        rt = function(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after")
        return rt
    return wrapped_func

def test_Test():
    test = SUT()
    test.function1 = my_decorator(test.function1)
    test.function1()
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are actually doing an infinite recursive call with your current solution.

Monkeypatch is to mock a dependency that can be tough to test. So you are misusing it in the above example.

If you wan't something printed before and after then do:

```
import pytest

class SUT:
    def function1(self):
        print("abc")

def test_Test(monkeypatch):
    test = SUT()
    print("before")
    test.function1()
    print("after")
```